Can you use the relative cell value of a cell using XLOOKUP to get a formula in Google Sheets
Context
I'm trying to recreate a minigame to make a basic "heatmap" of the best decision to make. To do this I first decided to recreate the functionality of the game. The game consists of a 7x7 board and different fruit around the board that provide different amounts of points. I've created a visual display of the board and a way to put in the history of moves, on a separate sheet I have the data I need for how many points each item would give for choosing it and to calculate the score, I use the XLOOKUP function to check what the user inputs as their move, and output how many points they would get for that move.
Problem
=IFERROR(IFS(OR(I1="Watermelon",I1="Durian",I1="Dragonfruit"),0.5,I1="Pomegranate",1.5,TRUE,1) \* XLOOKUP(I2,Data!$A$3:$A$13,Data!$B$3:$B$13),0)


The dragonfruit, and durian halve the score of the next choice and pomegranate multiplies it by 1.5, which is what the first IFS statement is for. It shouldn't have any impact on the question I have.
The goal of this and all similar cells is to calculate the score you would get from said "turn", for example if you tell the sheet you got a "Mango" on your choice, it would check Data!$A$3:$A:13 for the corresponding text in the Data sheet, then use the corresponding formula to that text. This seemed like the best solution to this instead of having 12 different IFS in each cell.
The problem I have is there are 2 fruit that give more points based on how many times you have previously found the same kind, but I can't figure out a way to be able to count how many times that fruit has been chosen before the current choice, I'm assuming this is because the XLOOKUP is just taking the result of the cell it's referencing, not using the formula in the cell at it's own position.
I've tried using the FORMULATEXT() function to get the text of the formula and use it somehow, but I haven't had any luck with that working.
As I said before I've been trying to use
=IFERROR(IFS(OR(I1="Watermelon",I1="Durian",I1="Dragonfruit"),0.5,I1="Pomegranate",1.5,TRUE,1) * XLOOKUP(I2,Data!$A$3:$A$13,Data!$B$3:$B$13),0)


which would be referencing
=200 + (COUNTIF(Board!$I$2:ROW(B8),"Cherry")*300)

This was the last thing I tried hoping the ROW(B8) referencing itself, would reference the cell using the XLOOKUP. I've tried looking up ways to have a cell use a formula of another cell, without just taking the output of said cell, but wasn't able to find a solution, I'm assuming either this would be the solution I'm looking for but I haven't had any success in finding a way to do this yet without just putting all of the different possibilities for the inputs in a big IFS statement, which I wanted to avoid if possible.

it would check Data!$A$3:$A:13 for the corresponding text in the Data sheet, then use the corresponding formula to that text. With respect, this is a very long question and it is written as though the user knows the layout of the spreadsheet, data fields, rules, etc. I'm sorry but I have found that the scenario and the problem are not clear. Would you please edit the question to provide more focus on the technical issue, and include sample data, and an example of the expected outcome.
